# Getting Let's encrypt cerificate to work with android api < 20

Tags: android, ssl, react-native, websocket, lets-encrypt

I have a node server which uses Let's Encrypt CA and it's hosted on zeit.now.
The client is developed using react-native.
I try to connect to it using websockets.

On iOS and newer Android versions (API > 20) it connects successfully.

When running on older Android versions (both on simulator and actual devices) it never connects.

I have tried to connect using older Android version to a server that's not using Let's encrypt CA (but IS using ssl from other provider - hosted on heroku), and it also connects successfully.

So I believe there is something wrong with older Android versions and Let's encrypt certificate.

Could someone help? I have lost 5 days researching this problem and I don't know a lot about JAVA.

EDIT:
I try to connect using websocket

```
    ws.onerror = (e) => {
      // an error occurred
      console.log(e.message);
    };
```

this logs:

```
Connection closed by peer
```

and this method:

```
    ws.onclose = (e) => {
      // connection closed
      console.log(e.code, e.reason);
    };
```

logs:

```
undefined, undefined
```

Comment: You may need to use certificate pinning to teach your app and Android that the certificate that you are using is OK. I am not a React Native developer, though, and so I do not know what options you have there for certificate pinning. In more traditional Android development, you could use OkHttp's support for certificate pinning, or perhaps use [my backport of Android 7.0+'s network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity).

Comment: Although I don't quite understand what certificate pinning is, I imagine that this means that Let's encrypt certificate is not recognized as valid? As far as I know, react native is using Okhttp because I can see it in these 2 files: https://github.com/tuncaulubilge/react-native/blob/a6d30f7fadd05b35482e7120e4fc3049feec15ad/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/OkHttpClientProvider.java , https://github.com/tuncaulubilge/react-native/blob/a6d30f7fadd05b35482e7120e4fc3049feec15ad/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/TLSSocketFactory.java @Commons

Comment: "I imagine that this means that Let's encrypt certificate is not recognized as valid?" -- my assumption is that the Android SDK and framework classes do not recognize the Let's Encrypt root certificate. Let's Encrypt seems to think that they should be fine on API Level 11+, but they may be focusing on mobile browsers (which can bundle and use their own root certificate list). I haven't tried reaching a Let's Encrypt server from an Android app, and so I don't know exactly what may be going on here.

Comment: That's weird, because when I try to access the server using the browser on those older devices, I am able to connect to it. Doesn't this mean that Android trust this certificate? Sorry if all these are stupid questions, but it's the first time I get involved with these certificates. @CommonsWare

Comment: "Doesn't this mean that Android trust this certificate?" -- Android itself provides a stock set of root certificates for apps to use. Apps can create and use their own set of root certificates, and I would expect major browser apps to do that. So, it is not surprising to see a browser be able to access a Let's Encrypt server where an ordinary app cannot without additional work.

Comment: So do you mean that Google updates those sets of certificates with each Android api it launches, and it might be possible that on older android version it wasn't included, whereas in newer it is and thus I am able to connect when using android API > 20?

Comment: On newer versions of Android, Google updates the certificates periodically. On older versions of Android, it is part of the firmware and only gets updated if the manufacturer happens to update them (IOW, never). I forget whether the switchover occurred at 4.4 or 5.0, but it was somewhere around there.

Comment: In the emulator, I successfully connected to a Let's Encrypt cert with Android 19 and 17. However, a problem could be TLS support. Can you post the stack trace you're getting?

Comment: @Shred How can i get the stack trace?

Comment: @Shred I edited the question to show the errors I am getting when console logging. Is there a way to get more info about what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! See this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18032#issuecomment-369266431).
Basically I needed to install the latest security fixes that are bundled with Google Play Services

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the following dependency to Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
```

and then calling

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
          ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // Don't forget exception handling!
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // Do something clever  
    }
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
}
```